Terraform error operation error DynamoDB: PutItem, https response error StatusCode: 400,
There are some parts I don't understand and what I've missed when working on my tutorial.
this is my backend.tf file.
terraform {
  backend "s3" {
    bucket         = "my-ews-baket1.0"
    region         = "ap-southeast-1"
    key            = "End-to-End-Kubernetes-Three-Tier-DevSecOps-Project/Jenkins-Server-TF/terraform.tfstate"
    dynamodb_table = "Lock-Files"
    encrypt        = true
  }
  required_version = ">=0.13.0"
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      version = ">= 2.7.0"
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
    }
  }
}

terraform init was success but when I try to run terraform plan -var-file="variables.tfvars" command it gives me this error.
Error: Error acquiring the state lock
│
│ Error message: 2 errors occurred:
│       * operation error DynamoDB: PutItem, https response error StatusCode: 400, RequestID: GR14O7ASBU1MPCN838P2JSCL97VV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG, api error ValidationException: One or more
│ parameter values were invalid: Missing the key id in the item
│       * Unable to retrieve item from DynamoDB table "Lock-Files": operation error DynamoDB: GetItem, https response error StatusCode: 400, RequestID:
│ DU7CSJE7862EV8O4IBG4GBEU6BVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG, api error ValidationException: The provided key element does not match the schema

I already created the dynamodb table named 'Lock-Files' and gave full access to IAM user as well. I tried 'terraform force-unlock' command but not worked. want your help to resolve this issue.

The exception is very clear, you've configured your table with a partition key of id and that key didn't exist in the items you tried to insert.
Make sure you have the key id for each item.
